# fixing a failed ruby gem install

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am installing the ruby gem mysql-dbd on a new system which is running ruby 2.5.  The problem is that it gets a syntax error because at 2.4 ruby combined Integer and Fixed num types.

The failed install leaves the unpacked gem package on disk so I was able to examine the entrails and the fix appears to be trivial (as in insert a '#' in a statement to remove the now redundant reference to FixNum).

My question is having fixed the source how do I go about building and installing the gem?   Not being familiar with rake.

BTW the gem has long been "unsupported".

Answer (score 1):

I can't get the gem source repository to load, but you've got at least two options:

Locally, you might be able to build it. Try running `rake build` from the root folder of the gem, and look in the `pkg` folder for the built gem. You should be able to then `gem install pkg/<gem name>.gem` in that folder

If you need to share it with others, push the code up on github. Make your change, and if you're using bundler in the codebase that's using the gem, update your Gemfile to point to your source.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
# install_dbd_mysql.rb

Fixnum = Integer

require 'rubygems/commands/install_command'

install = Gem::Commands::InstallCommand.new
install.handle_options ['dbd-mysql']
install.execute
```

Run:

```
$ ruby install_dbd_mysql.rb
```